# Python subprocess: using a string variable as command

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to assemble commands based on input to the python script, but I am having trouble with subprocess.check_output recognizing the string. Here is an example.

```
 str1 = "./program.sh %lf %lf" % (x0, x1)
 sim_flux230 = subprocess.check_output(str1)
```

It keeps saying there is no such file or directory in reference to str1. How can I get subprocess to recognize the string str is holding rather than literally checking for a file called str1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shlex.html) and see if it helps:

```
import shlex

str1 = "./program.sh %lf %lf" % (x0, x1)
sim_flux230 = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(str1))
```

Generally speaking, if you do not have `shell=True` (i.e. `subprocess.check_output(str1, shell=True)`), then the command needs to be passed in as a list. It's also [not safe to use `shell=True`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

Answer (score 1):

When you use `subprocess` with `shell=False`, you have to pass your arguments as a list. You can only pass them as a string using `shell=True`. Your code should work if you do this:

```
cmd = ["./program.sh", x0, x1]
sim_flux230 = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
```